# div width issue with table cell padding in Outlook for rounded corners on div elsewhere

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

**This question severly changed after further testing**

I have a table layout something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="padding:10px 3%;">
      <div border="2px solid #000000;">
          <table><tr><td style="padding:10px 7%;">Text 'n' stuff</td></tr></table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the div, with border, is getting cut off on the right. It appears to me that the div is the full width of the child table, plus the extra 14% for the total padding. This extends the border out to the right a bit then cuts it off.

[image]

Removing the table-tr-td inside the div, but leaving the content otherwise intact, fixes the sizing problem. Setting the `td` padding to zero also fixes the div width issue. But, I need the inner table for its padding. This happens in Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013.

I need the div for its ability to round corners, in other email clients.

Any idea how to do this without a conditional?

Answer (score 1):

For every asinine problem with a MS technology, there's an equally concealed solution. I'm not certain if that's good or bad, but here's the fix:

On the div, set the border and radius as you expect, but then cancel it out with the `mso-border-*-alt` properties:

```
overflow:hidden;border:2px solid #58bce9;border-radius:5px;mso-border-right-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;mso-border-bottom-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;mso-border-left-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;mso-border-top-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;
```

Effectively removing the div's broken borders in Outlook. The `overflow:hidden;` is to account for the background color of the table's square corners overlapping the rounded corners of the div.

On the table, I then used:

```
mso-border-right-alt: 2px solid #58bce9;mso-border-bottom-alt:2px solid #58bce9;mso-border-left-alt: 2px solid #58bce9;mso-border-top-alt:2px solid #58bce9;
```

To apply the borders to the table only in Outlook.

Tada!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout this [guide to email client CSS compatibility.](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) And the [MSDN guide to what's acceptable in outlook.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)

I see border-radius isn't supported by the outlook 7/10/13 clients so you may want to try removing that to see if it's causing the formatting errors.

Comment: The compatibility guide and MSDN guide say nothing about border issues with divs. 

Removing border-radius has no effect. (to my knowledge) All rendering engines ignore properties they don't understand.

Comment: Solution was found using mso proprietaries.